# Does mobile phone user density in an area affect signal reception?

Tags: radio

Whenever I go to a very crowded area (like during New Year celebration), where a lot of people gather in a space, usually my phone's data connection becomes very bad and even stopped working. Even the "EDGE/3G" indicator will go missing. Is this caused by the density of the mobile phone user (perhaps the signal interfere each other or something)? This has occurred several times before, but I'm not quite sure whether it's telco problem, or my mobile phone problem or any other reason.

Comment: A given cell can only handle so many users at high speed. Only so many time slices to go around. So, with more people you get fewer time slices...